# How can I make Git forget/remove a deleted file that has an invalid filename?

Tags: git, github, cmder

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xutX.jpg)

I'm not sure how, but a co-worker created a file with an invalid name (slash in file name, "MCHS \226 FH La Crosse.xlsx"). This file has been deleted now, but I can't seem to get git to forget about it. I'm still able to pull/push/commit but I've been staring at this message every time I sync my repos for the past year now, and today I decided I've had enough and I need it gone.

I tried to do a git rm but I got the error "did not match any files". I can't physically recreate a file with that filename, to complete the rm, because of the slash in the name...any suggestions?

Comment: Git has issues on Windows with file names that work fine on Linux.  (Those of us who use Macs should not be too smug as it has similar issues on HFS file systems that do case folding. :-) But we at least have *options*.)  You should be able to `git rm --cached` the path, but if it has been gone for a year it should not be showing up at all at this point, unless you keep checking out old commits where it is present.  Your screenshot suggests that the file is not, and was never, actually deleted in more recent commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git rm -r --cached -- "path/to/directory"

git pull

git rm "path/to/directory"

git add "path/to/directory"

git push

git pull
```

Answer (score 1):

`git rm` is to remove existing files from your index and/or working tree. It won't do anything for a file that has already been deleted. Instead, you probably have to commit the file deletion.

In the terminal, `$ git status` in your project. You should see something like

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    MCHS \226 FH La Crosse.xlsx
```

Add the file and commit it:

```
git add "MCHS \\226 FH La Crosse.xlsx"
git commit -m "remove deleted file from remote repo"
```

Finally, push to your remote repo.

Comment: hm, this sounds promising. I'm going to try it out and I'll get back to you.

Edit: No luck yet. received the following error when trying to `git add`

fatal: pathspec 'MCHS \\226 FH La Crosse.xlsx' did not match any files
@amacrobert

Comment: @peterxgriffin what is the output from `git status`?

Comment: it's pretty much what you had listed in your first code block in the original answer:

`Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    "Conversion Scripts/Mayo/LookUpMerge/Category-Status-StaffType--FINAL/RemainingBlanks/MCHS \226 FH La Crosse.xlsx"

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")`

Comment: @peterxgriffin you need to provide the relative path to the file you want to add. So in your case, `git add "Conversion Scripts/Mayo/LookUpMerge/Category-Status-StaffType--FINAL/RemainingBlanks/MCHS \226 FH La Crosse.xlsx"`